# Directory not found when using Drat on a network drive

Tags: r, drat

I have developed a package that I want to share with my colleagues at work.

I have a network drive in which I created the local repository structure that looks like this:

```
MyRepo
\__bin
   \__windows
      \__contrib
\__src
   \__contrib
```

All folders are empty.

So I built my package with RStudio on Windows using the "Build/More/Build source package" menu, which created a tar.gz file.

Then I tried:

```
drat::insertPackage("../myPkg_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz",
                    repodir = "file://networkdrive/path/to/MyRepo",
                    action = "prune")
```

But this gives me an error:

```
Error: Directory file://networkdrive/path/to/MyRepo not found
```

Which is strange because `file.exists(//networkdrive/path/to/MyRepo)` returns true.

OK, then I tried:

```
drat::insertPackage("../myPkg_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz",
                    repodir = "//networkdrive/path/to/MyRepo",
                    action = "prune")
```

Without the `file:` in the repository path and I get another error:

```
tar (child): "//networkdrive/path/to/MyRepo/src/contrib/myPkg_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
/usr/bin/tar: Child returned status 2
/usr/bin/tar: myPkg/DESCRIPTION: Not found in archive
/usr/bin/tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
reading DESCRIPTION for package ‘myPkg’ failed with message:
  cannot open the connection
```

But when I go in the "//networkdrive/path/to/MyRepo/src/contrib" folder, I can definitely see the myPkg_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz file that has been copied despite the error message.

Can anyone help?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252    LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] drat_0.1.2   tools_3.3.3  git2r_0.18.0
```

Comment: I _think_ you need three slashes for `file:///`.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work :(

Comment: Network drives are evil.  At work we push sources using an absolute path but consume the drat content via http.   You may need to do some local debugging---the underlying commands are all simple (ie `file.copy()` and alike) but well ensuring paths are sane is more of a local issue...

Comment: OK, so I downloaded the source code of version 0.1.2. When I don't use `file:`, the error message is generated by line 103 in insertPackage.R: write_PACKAGES(pkgdir, type=pkgtype, ...). When I use `file:`, it fails fast at line 57. dir.exists(repodir) returns false because R is looking for a file whose path starts with "file:" which it cannot find, of course.

Comment: That's good progress. We'd now need to find another use by R of a "similar" directory.  The base R packages utils and tools work on this, they may do some path "filtering" or "adjusting".  It would be terrific if you could work this out as I am not normally on Windows.

Comment: Well, not easy :). In your package, the main problem is that file.exists and dir.exists do not work on URL (e.g. path starting with `file:`). I tried a very dirty hack, using `repodir = "//networkdrive/path/to/MyRepo"` and replacing the call to write_PACKAGES by `write_PACKAGES(paste("file:/", pkgdir, sep = ""), type=pkgtype, ...)` but it crashes later on anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after some research, here is my conclusions.

- It cannot be done
- It's not Drat's fault

The reason why it does not work is that the `tools::write_PACKAGES` function does not work on network drives. Period.

I manually copied my package on the network drive, then ran `setwd()` to its location and executed `write_PACKAGES(".", type="source")` and I got the same error.

So to make this work, I just left my package.tar.gz file on a local drive, ran the `tools::write_PACKAGES` command locally and then moved the files to the network drive.

Adding the network drive to my repository list using `options(repos = c(MyRepo = "file://networkdrive/path/to/MyRepo/"))` works: RStudio and `available.packages` find my package.

It's not completely satisfactory, but I think it's the only way today.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but my colleague just came across the same problem and found this post.  I believe the issue may be the lack of a trailing slash in your directory name.  I have been able to recreate the error with a *mapped* network drive.  I can resolve the issue by using "H:/MyRepo/" instead of "H:/MyRepo".

I haven't tried it with the "file://" format, but I wanted to include my answer in case someone else comes across this question.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem as well and finally got to the bottom of it today.

For me, the problem was not isolated to just network locations but also occurred on C: drive. The root cause was the version of tar.exe being used to unpack the existing packages in the package directory.  Calls to `utils::untar` are made in the `tools::write_PACKAGES` function.

The documentation for [utils::untar](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/untar.html) explains that on Windows, external tar.exe is tried first.  Sure enough, I had a version installed with Git which when used with default arguments fails when a colon is in the file name.  I was able to force `utils::untar` to use to use the RBuildTools version of tar.exe instead by setting the environment variable TAR to "internal".

`drat::insertPackage` now works.

Comment: "I was able to force utils::untar to use the RBuildTools" how did you do that?

Comment: @Ben Either set a Windows environment variable TAR to "internal" or from within R Sys.setenv("TAR"="internal")